# How to stop a subprocess from execution on Windows and Linux

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

How do I stop a subprocess from running?

I tried on windows:

```
__process.kill()
__process.terminate()
```

and I also tried:

```
os.kill(self.__process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

in the end I made it stop waiting in a while loop the subprocess for a word and I was using:

```
self.__process.communicate(input='quit')
```

but I don't want to wait for an input.
Thank you.

Comment: "I tried" – What happened when you tried? Did an error occur? Did nothing happen or something unexpected?

Comment: The process was running in the background.Still

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. See the [ask] page how to best help us help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a process group so as to enable sending a signal to all the process in the groups. For that, you should attach a session id to the parent process of the spawned/child processes. So now, when a signal is sent to the process  it's transmitted to all of the child processes of this group.

Here's the code:

```py
import os
import signal
import subprocess

# The os.setsid() is passed in the argument preexec_fn so
# it's run after the fork() and before  exec() to run the shell.
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I also need for windows, it is a cross platform application.